# How to escape from use PreparedStatement.setNull?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I have a very big table in my DataBase. Some of they fields may be null.

I just want to escape from use the:

```
PreparedStatement.setNull(index, Type.X)
```

Like:

```
if(obj.getSomaData() == null){
  insertStmt.setNull(++i, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
}else{
  insertStmt.setString(++i, obj.getSomaData());
}
```

There's a better and cleaner way to do this?

P.S.: I'm using PostgreSQL.

Comment: Do you mean that you don't want to use the `setNull()` method? If you're `INSERT`ing data, you don't need to explicitly set values `NULL` because absent values will be `NULL` by default.

Comment: I think the Postgres JDBC driver will handle `setString(index, null)` just fine

Comment: @MickMnemonic That is only true if those columns are not included in the insert statement, if they are included, a JDBC driver should give an exception for values not explicitly set. See JDBC 4.2 section 13.2.2: _"The methods used to execute a `PreparedStatement` object (`executeQuery`, `executeUpdate` and `execute`) will throw an `SQLException` if a value is not supplied for a parameter marker."_

Comment: @Mark, yes, not using `setNull()` in the `INSERT` statement would then mean that you need to dynamically add the correct number of bind placeholders and also generate the column list dynamically. And doing all this is probably not worth it, especially if you're inserting multiple rows with the same statement. So as your answer suggests, there's no need for specific `null` handling.

Answer (score 6):

The primary use case of `setNull` is for setting primitive types to null, and to handle some edge cases where the driver can't know the data types of the parameters and needs to be explicitly instructed.

In most cases you should be able to use `setString(idx, null)` (or a `setXXX` of another object type) just fine.

To quote JDBC 4.2 section 13.2.2.4:

> If a Java `null` is passed to any of the setter methods that take a Java object, the parameter will be set to JDBC `NULL`.

An exception is made for an 'untyped' `null` (eg using `setObject`), where it is suggested that for maximum portability you should use `setNull` or the `setObject` that takes a type parameter as not all database support that without type information.